# How come Django doesn't email me errors when my DEBUG = False?

Tags: python, django, debugging, email, settings

```
ADMINS = [("alex", "alex@mydomain.com"), ("matt", "matt@mydomain.com")]

DEBUG = False
```

How come Django doesn't email me errors? I set up the email settings correctly, and everything else can send email just fine.

```
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.blah.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "blah"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "blah"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "blah@blah.com"
```

I want to be emailed all errors that occurred. (even though I have my own try /except blocks everywhere).

Comment: What's SERVER_EMAIL set to?  If it's using the "root@localhost" default, it will likely get flagged as spam.

Comment: What version of django you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From django documentation on [error-reporting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/error-reporting/):

> By default, Django will send e-mail
>   from root@localhost. However, some
>   mail providers reject all e-mail from
>   this address. To use a different
>   sender address, modify the
>   SERVER_EMAIL setting.

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I've found that helps me debug the email subsystem in django is a setup that displays the email content (headers and all) to standard out.  I've summarized below, but you can also find more info about in the django documentation (link below).  Not sure if it will help you in your case, but it might help debug the issue ... help you see what's being sent.

Set the following in settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Run the following to host the test webserver

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Django documentation: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

Comment: Well, my email sends just fine. I use my settings to send email everywhere. It's just that the admin debug doesn't get triggered.